# How to create bootstrapped datasets from repeated measures over time for further calculation?

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

I have a repeated measurements dataset (one year, biweekly gas flux data) with 10 treatments (4 replicates per treatment), looking like this:

```
          date spot site CH4.units CH4.pv CH4.flux  t.air
1   2019-06-21    1   LV        mg      .  -0.0430 16.480
2   2019-06-21    2   SE        mg      .   0.0579 16.480
3   2019-06-21    4   SV        mg     **   0.0228 16.480
4   2019-06-21    6   LV        mg     **   0.0454 16.480
5   2019-06-21    7   SE        mg      .   0.0374 11.140
6   2019-06-21   11   LV        mg      *   0.3342 11.140
7   2019-06-21   12   SE        mg      .   0.1658 11.140
8   2019-06-21   13    V        mg      *   0.2188 11.140
9   2019-06-21   14   SV        mg      .   0.5113 16.480
10  2019-06-21   17   SE        mg      *   0.0410 11.140
11  2019-06-21   18    Ø        mg      *  -0.1903 11.140
12  2019-06-21   19   SV        mg     **   0.6110 11.140
13  2019-06-21   20    V        mg     **  -0.1024 11.140
14  2019-06-21   21   LV        mg      *  -0.0575 16.480
15  2019-06-21   24   SV        mg      .   0.3653 16.480
16  2019-06-21   25    Ø        mg     **  -0.0449 16.480
17  2019-07-05    2   SE        mg      *  -0.0250 23.120
18  2019-07-05    4   SV        mg      *   0.0000 17.160
19  2019-07-05    5    V        mg      *   0.0494 17.160
20  2019-07-05    6   LV        mg      .   0.0000 17.160
21  2019-07-05    8    Ø        mg      *   0.0863 17.160
22  2019-07-05   13    V        mg      *  -0.2023 17.160
23  2019-07-05   14   SV        mg      *  -0.0328 17.160
24  2019-07-05   15    V        mg      *   0.0194 17.160
25  2019-07-05   17   SE        mg      .  -0.0688 17.160
26  2019-07-05   18    Ø        mg     **   0.4213 23.120
27  2019-07-05   19   SV        mg      *   0.0718 23.120
28  2019-07-05   20    V        mg      .   0.1394 17.160
......... etc.
```

What I want is to create 100 annual datasets per treatment (site) by randomly picking one or two of the available fluxes of the four replicates in each treatment for each measurement day so that I later can estimate 100 annual gas balances for the datasets each time omitting one measurement day (jackknife method). The idea behind is to avoid over-/underestimation and to include estimates of the uncertainty associated with linear interpolation for annual balances.

But how on earth do I do that? Any tips & tricks are appreciated!